# Casting a member access func from Func<DerivedFromT,object> to Func<T,object>

Tags: c#, linq, casting, expression, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to creating a dynamic base mapping with fluent nhibernate.

What I'm doing is checking in by a BaseMap< T > : ClassMap< T > if for example:
                (typeof(ICategorizedEntity).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))

If so, I wanna map a property named "Category" which belongs to ICategorizedEntity's interface, but the Map(Func) function only accepts T's properties, so I tried guessing a little with linq and came up with this:

```
   Expression<Func<ICategorizedEntity, object>> exp = x => x.Category;
   var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T));
   var lmd = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(exp, parameter);
   Map(lmd);
```

Which doesn't work, because deep inside the 'Map' function it checks the following:

```
   MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression) null;
   if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
       memberExpression = ((UnaryExpression) expression).Operand as MemberExpression;
   else if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
       memberExpression = expression as MemberExpression;
   if (enforceCheck && memberExpression == null)
       throw new ArgumentException("Not a member access", "expression");
```

And I get the "Not a member access\r\nParameter name: expression".

How can I create and cast a MemberExpression or anything similar which will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Douglas, you lead me to the right (simple) answer.

I went too far trying to find it..

Good old conversion (inside the lambda expression) did the trick:

```
   Map(x => ((ICategorizedEntity)x).Category);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Func<DerivedFromT,object>` represents a method that accepts a `DerivedFromT` parameter. `Func<T,object>` represents a method that accepts a `T` parameter. Through [delegate variance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233060.aspx) introduced in C# 4, you can cast `Func<T,object>` to `Func<DerivedFromT,object>`, but not the other way round (as you’re requesting).

Think about what this means:

```
public class Person { }

public class Student : Person { }

public static class School
{
    public static object Greet(Person person)
    {
        return null; 
    }

    public static object Promote(Student student)
    { 
        return null; 
    }
}
```

In this case, the `Greet` method matches the delegate `Func<Person,object>`, whilst the `Promote` method matches the delegate `Func<Student,object>`.

```
Func<Person, object> greetPerson = School.Greet;
Func<Student, object> promoteStudent = School.Promote;
```

We can cast `Greet` to `Func<Student,object>`; if we can greet a `Person`, then we can also greet a `Student` (who is guaranteed to be a specialized form of `Person`).

```
Func<Student, object> greetStudent = greetPerson;
```

However, we cannot cast `Promote` to `Func<Person,object>`; although we can promote a `Student`, we cannot promote any `Person` in general, unless he/she happens to be a `Student`.

```
Func<Person, object> promotePerson = promoteStudent;   // Will not compile.
```

If we know that our `Person` is a student, we can indicate this by casting it:

```
Func<Person, object> promotePerson =
    personWhoIsActuallyStudent => promoteStudent((Student)personWhoIsActuallyStudent);
```

Comment: Thanks for you nice explanation Douglas, But I think you misunderstood what I tried to achieve.. 

Good old conversion did the trick:

       Map(x => ((ICategorizedEntity)x).Category);

Comment: I admit that I really didn’t understand your question, so my post was based mostly on your title. However, I assumed that the answer would probably lie in my last line of code, which performs the in-lambda cast you required.